# Intellij IDEA 2016+ mute plugin Error popup

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I'm doing some wanna-be Plugin in Idea SDK- but when testing (by-hand) some basics I see this popup.

[image]

After seeing it for 100th time it gets **really** annoying.

**Question:** 
How can I disable this popup with it's companion, the blinking red icon?
Both are being displayed on exception, appearing in **bottom right** corner of main UI window. When the pop disappears- the flashing icon stays.

Comment: Click on `See Details` and fix the problem that will be reported :) It's most likely an exception thrown by your plugin.